# SELECT clause in FOR LOOP control using plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, select, for-loop, plpgsql

I try to make a script as to output all the foos that are used by only one user, if a foo is used by more than one user, it shouldn't be outputed.

here's my tables

```
foos  (id, value)
users (id, name)
used  (foo_id, user_id)
```

and my not working script

```
FUNCTION output_unshared_foos ()
RETURNS foos AS
$a$
DECLARE
  foocounts RECORD;
BEGIN
  SELECT u.foo_id, count(*)
  INTO foocounts -- store in the local variable
  FROM used u
  GROUP BY u.foo_id;

  FOR f IN SELECT * FROM foos
  LOOP
    IF (SELECT fc.count < 2 FROM foocounts fc WHERE fc.foo_id = f.id) THEN
      RETURN NEXT f;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END
$a$ language plpgsql;
```

doesn't seem to work, every rows are returned and the conditional control seems to be always true.

Comment: Hand-crafted table definitions are far less useful than what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. And you forgot to declare your version of Postgres. Also, what you present is syntactically invalid and would produce an error message, not a result.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you can't store the result of a query that returns more than one row into a single variable (the `SELECT u.foo_id, count(*) INTO ...` part). I'm surprised you don't get a runtime error when you call your function.

Your function also doesn't compile because the record `f` is not declared and a functioned defined as `returns foos` can't use `return next`

But your approach is wrong (even if it worked). Doing row-by-row processing is almost always the wrong choice in SQL. SQL and relational databases are meant to handle sets, not single rows.

Your problem can be solved with a single query:

```
select foo_id
from used
group by foo_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 1
```

will return all foo ids that are used by exactly one user.

If you need the additional information from the `foos` table, you can join the above query to the foos table:

```
select f.*
from foos f
  join (
     select foo_id
     from used
     group by foo_id
     having count(distinct user_id) = 1
  ) u on f.id = u.foo_id
```

Comment: thanks, but i should have mentioned i am using a function because before `returning next f` i need to make some treatment in my table..

Comment: @발렌텐: you should always state your **complete** requirements when asking a question. But that sounds as if you just need an additional `where` clause to my second query

Comment: @발렌텐: plus you can always iterate over the result of my second query. You would still be doing that slow row-by-row processing but it would stzill be faster than your solution.